# Pretty JSON format in Python

Tags: python, json, format

Хочу записать в файл структуру :

```
class MyData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_nID = 0
        self.m_strTitle = ""

    def serialize(self):
        temp_dict = {
            'ID': self.m_nID,
            'Title': self.m_strTitle}
        return temp_dict

def setData2File(a_data, a_str_path):
    file = open(a_str_path, "w")
    json.dump(a_data, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ... work ... work ... work
    for result in arrResults:
        FileUtils.setData2File(result.serialize() , "test.json")
```

В файл все прекрасно записывается, НО:
почему то с форматированием, т.е. 
     "{ \"Title\": \"Питоны— Википедия\",\"ID\": 1}"

Я уже долго мучаюсь и никак не могу понять в чем проблема, как мне вывести pretty вариант без слешей и прочих лишних символов?

Comment: Ваш open неправильный. По умолчанию он открывается в режиме чтения, так что ваш код ничего не записывает. Попробуйте: `open(a_str_path, 'w')`

Comment: Да, это я ошиблась при написании вопроса.  Но это не более опечатки. Я только начинаю работать с python, поэтому возможно в моей логике есть ошибки.

Comment: Вы можете привести пример значения для `result` из `FileUtils.setData2File(result.serialize() , "test.json")`?

Comment: Это, class MyData : self.m_nID = 0 - число (int)
        self.m_strTitle = "" - строка (str)

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести описанную проблему - у меня файл создается без слешей : `{ "ID": 0, "Title": "" }`

Comment: Попробуйте привести такой пример данных, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему...

Comment: Спасибо всем кто старался помочь. Произошла странная вещь, после перезагрузки Pycharm все стало работать. Похоже некоторые мои изменения в течении часа никак не влияли на программу?!?!